# Place all navigation items inline

Tags: html, css

Webpage Screenshot:
[image: Webpage Screenshot]

```css
/* All */
html {
 font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-image: url("Assets/Background_Image.jpg");
 color: white;
}


/*Navbar */
.navbar {
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
 width: 100%;
 float: top;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 2px solid gray;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.nav_align {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
}

.nav_logo {
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
 border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.nav_title {
 color: gray;
 background-color: aqua;
 padding: 3px;
}

.Main_Logo {
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 
}

.nav_sm {
}


.sm_list {
}

.sm_item img {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 float: top;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.nav_search {
 
}

.nav_btns {
 
}

.nav_list {
 
}

.nav_btn {
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 5px;
 background-color:#DCDCDC;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
}

.nav_btn:hover {
 background-color: #1E40FF;
 color: white;
 padding: 7px;
}
.navbar a:hover {
 color: white;
}

/*Navbar End */
```

```html
<?php 

require_once "Includes/db-Connect.php";

//session data will be here

?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheet.css"> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<title>Game Informer - Home</title>

<nav class="navbar">
 <ul class="nav_align">
 
  <li class="nav_align">
   <div class="nav_logo">
    <img src="Assets/Main_Logo.png" alt="Main_Logo" class="Main_Logo">
   </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav_align">
   <div class="nav_title">
    <h1>Game Informant</h1>
   </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav_align">
   <div class="nav_sm">
    <ul class="sm_list">
    
     <li class="sm_item"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/?gl=GB&hl=en-GB">
     <img src="Assets/YT_Logo.png" alt="youtube"></a></li>
     
     <li class="sm_item"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
     <img src="Assets/FB_Logo.png" alt="facebook"></a></li>
     
     <li class="sm_item"><a href="https://twitter.com/Twitter">
     <img src="Assets/TW_Logo.png" alt="twitter"></a></li>
     
    </ul>
   </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav_align">
   <form class="nav_search">
    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Non-Function">
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav_align">
   <div class="nav_btns">
    <ul class="nav_align">
     <li class="nav_btn"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
     <li class="nav_btn"><a href="questions.php">Questions</a></li>
     <li class="nav_btn"><a href="account.php">Account</a></li>
     <li class="nav_btn"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </li>
  
 </ul> 
</nav>



</head>

<hr>

<body>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<?php
require_once "Includes/db-Connect.php";
?>

<div class="sign_con">

 <button class="sign_button"><a href="Sign_In.php">Sign In</a></button>
 <button class="sign_button"><a href="Sign_Up.php">Sign Up</a></button>
 
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I am a computer science student and I need some help I can't get all my navigation items inline. I'm a huge beginner at this as it seems like a 2 minute fix but I am clueless as I've tried for about an hour now.

Comment: use these tow changes

Comment: Use float:left for the the elements that you want to be in one line. Also try to use Bootstrap library, it will ease your UI development. Also they have really good documentation on their website that will help you in further studies. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add below css..

```
.sm_list {
    list-style:none;
}
.sm_list > li {
    display: inline;
}
```

```css
/* All */
html {
 font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-image: url("Assets/Background_Image.jpg");
 color: white;
}


/*Navbar */
.navbar {
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
 width: 100%;
 float: top;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 2px solid gray;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.nav_align {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
}

.nav_logo {
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
 border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.nav_title {
 color: gray;
 background-color: aqua;
 padding: 3px;
}

.Main_Logo {
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 
}

.nav_sm {
}


.sm_list {
  list-style:none;
}
.sm_list > li {
  display: inline;
  }
.sm_item img {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 float: top;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.nav_search {
 
}

.nav_btns {
 
}

.nav_list {
 
}

.nav_btn {
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 5px;
 background-color:#DCDCDC;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
}

.nav_btn:hover {
 background-color: #1E40FF;
 color: white;
 padding: 7px;
}
.navbar a:hover {
 color: white;
}

/*Navbar End */
```

```html
<?php 

require_once "Includes/db-Connect.php";

//session data will be here

?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheet.css"> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<title>Game Informer - Home</title>

<nav class="navbar">
 <ul class="nav_align">
 
  <li class="nav_align">
   <div class="nav_logo">
    <img src="Assets/Main_Logo.png" alt="Main_Logo" class="Main_Logo">
   </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav_align">
   <div class="nav_title">
    <h1>Game Informant</h1>
   </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav_align">
   <div class="nav_sm">
    <ul class="sm_list">
    
     <li class="sm_item"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/?gl=GB&hl=en-GB">
     <img src="Assets/YT_Logo.png" alt="youtube"></a></li>
     
     <li class="sm_item"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
     <img src="Assets/FB_Logo.png" alt="facebook"></a></li>
     
     <li class="sm_item"><a href="https://twitter.com/Twitter">
     <img src="Assets/TW_Logo.png" alt="twitter"></a></li>
     
    </ul>
   </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav_align">
   <form class="nav_search">
    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Non-Function">
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav_align">
   <div class="nav_btns">
    <ul class="nav_align">
     <li class="nav_btn"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
     <li class="nav_btn"><a href="questions.php">Questions</a></li>
     <li class="nav_btn"><a href="account.php">Account</a></li>
     <li class="nav_btn"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </li>
  
 </ul> 
</nav>



</head>

<hr>

<body>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<?php
require_once "Includes/db-Connect.php";
?>

<div class="sign_con">

 <button class="sign_button"><a href="Sign_In.php">Sign In</a></button>
 <button class="sign_button"><a href="Sign_Up.php">Sign Up</a></button>
 
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use these two changes

```
.nav_align {
    list-style-type: none;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

use flexbox.

```
.nav_btn {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color:#DCDCDC;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
  width:160px;
  margin-top:20px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav_align {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```